# Can anonymous code be executed with clean slate data, like test methods?

Tags: developer-console

Is there a way to execute anonymous code in a way that existing data on the org is not accessible, like when test methods execute?

A proper test method cannot be used as they are only allowed in top level classes. The only way is then to write real test methods and that's just a load of work when I usually need these things to just quickly see if something works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, that cannot be done; test methods are special in that regard. The closest would probably be working in a sandbox with limited data or creating bespoke unit tests.

Comment: I think I might post this as an idea on the IdeaExchange. It has merit. That, or someone else should.

Comment: The idea has already been posted https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000inJZAAY

Comment: Voted; having a truly anonymous/test session would be great.

Comment: Ok, so no. It's good that it's in ideas already, thanks for the link.

Comment: If anyone is at Dreamforce and is reading this. Could they hunt down @thomas Dvornik [Twitter:amphro](https://twitter.com/amphro) and politely encourage him that it is a good idea. Any of the Developer Evangelism team would also be acceptable :)